# Blazor (c#) DXDatagrid (devexpress) : Problem with Master Detail editor when replacing the default command buttons with icons

Tags: c#, razor, devexpress, blazor

I created a C# project using Blazor and Devexpress DxDataGrid component to create a Master Detail View. Everything works fine using the default command buttons (New, Edit). When I replace the Master command default buttons with icons, I have no problem with the edition functions:
[image]

When I replace the detail default controls, the detail editor for adding or replacing rows doesn´t work:
[image]

When I keep the default command buttons, just for the detail, the master (with icons) and detail (with default buttons), all the master and detail editors works fine:
[image]

To reproduce the issue, please download and compile the devexpress project you can find at: [How to replace default command button with icons on DXDataGrid](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/t807225/blazor-data-grid-how-to-use-icons-instead-of-default-command-buttons)
The example shows how to replace the default buttons in a single grid.  In my test project I added a detail as it´s shown in the following piece of code (just replace all code in .razor file):

```
@page "/"
    @using CommandButtonsWithIcons.Data
    @inject WeatherForecastService ForecastService

    @if (forecasts == null) {
        <h1>Loading...</h1>
    }
    else {
    <DxDataGrid Data=@forecasts ShowFilterRow=false CssClass="MainGrid" @ref="MyGrid"    ShowDetailRow="true"
                RowUpdating=@((updatingDataItem, newValues) => OnRowUpdating(updatingDataItem, newValues))
                RowInserting=@((newValues) => OnRowInserting(newValues))>
        <Columns>
            <DxDataGridCommandColumn>
                <HeaderCellTemplate>
                    <a class="oi oi-plus" @onclick="@(() => MyGrid.StartRowEdit(null))" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
                </HeaderCellTemplate>
                <CellTemplate>
                    <a class="oi oi-pencil" @onclick="@(() => MyGrid.StartRowEdit(context))" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
                    <a class="oi oi-x" @onclick="@(() => Delete(context as WeatherForecast))" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
                </CellTemplate>
            </DxDataGridCommandColumn>
            <DxDataGridColumn Field=@nameof(WeatherForecast.TemperatureC) Caption="Temp. (C)"></DxDataGridColumn>
            <DxDataGridColumn Field=@nameof(WeatherForecast.TemperatureF) Caption="Temp. (F)"></DxDataGridColumn>
            <DxDataGridComboBoxColumn Field=@nameof(WeatherForecast.Summary) Caption="Summary" Data=@summaries></DxDataGridComboBoxColumn>
            <DxDataGridDateEditColumn Field=@nameof(WeatherForecast.Date) DisplayFormatString="dd/MM/yyyy"
                                      EditFormatString="dd/MM/yyyy"></DxDataGridDateEditColumn>
        </Columns>
        <DetailRowTemplate Context="dataItem">
            <DxDataGrid Data=@forecasts.Where(x=>x.TemperatureC==dataItem.TemperatureC) ShowFilterRow=false CssClass="MainGrid" @ref="MyGridDetail"
                        RowUpdating=@((updatingDataItem, newValues) => OnRowUpdating(updatingDataItem, newValues))
                        RowInserting=@((newValues) => OnRowInserting(newValues))>
                <DxDataGridCommandColumn>
                    <HeaderCellTemplate>
                        <a class="oi oi-plus" @onclick="@(() => MyGridDetail.StartRowEdit(null))" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
                    </HeaderCellTemplate>
                    <CellTemplate>
                        <a class="oi oi-pencil" @onclick="@(() => MyGridDetail.StartRowEdit(context))" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
                        <a class="oi oi-x" @onclick="@(() => Delete(context as WeatherForecast))" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
                    </CellTemplate>
                </DxDataGridCommandColumn>
                <DxDataGridColumn Field=@nameof(WeatherForecast.TemperatureC) Caption="Temp. (C)"></DxDataGridColumn>
                <DxDataGridColumn Field=@nameof(WeatherForecast.TemperatureF) Caption="Temp. (F)"></DxDataGridColumn>
                <DxDataGridComboBoxColumn Field=@nameof(WeatherForecast.Summary) Caption="Summary" Data=@summaries></DxDataGridComboBoxColumn>
                <DxDataGridDateEditColumn Field=@nameof(WeatherForecast.Date) DisplayFormatString="dd/MM/yyyy"
                                          EditFormatString="dd/MM/yyyy"></DxDataGridDateEditColumn>
            </DxDataGrid>
        </DetailRowTemplate>

    </DxDataGrid>
    }
    @functions {
        WeatherForecast[] forecasts;
        string[] summaries;
        DevExpress.Blazor.DxDataGrid<WeatherForecast> MyGrid;
        DevExpress.Blazor.DxDataGrid<WeatherForecast> MyGridDetail;
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
            forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync();
            summaries = await ForecastService.GetSummariesAsync();
        }

        async void OnRowUpdating(WeatherForecast dataItem, Dictionary<string, object> newValue) {
            forecasts = await ForecastService.Update(dataItem, newValue);
        }
        async void OnRowInserting(Dictionary<string, object> newValue) {
            forecasts = await ForecastService.Insert(newValue);
        }

        async void Delete(WeatherForecast item) {
            if (item != null) {
                forecasts = await ForecastService.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE** As Paul V from devexpress suggests, we have to create a new razor component that implements a new DXDatagrid component instance, since it is not suitable to reference the component, 2 or more times on the same razor component. So, to fix the problem, create another component (ie. DetaiGrid) and reference it inside **DetailRowTemplate** and send a a parameter, the master record and the detail source :

```
 <DetailRowTemplate Context="dataItem">
    <DetailGrid MasterRecord="@dataItem" ForecastService="@ForecastService" Forecasts="@forecasts" ></DetailGrid>
</DetailRowTemplate>
```

Detail Example:

```
    <h3>DetailGrid2</h3>
            @using CommandButtonsWithIcons.Data


            <DxDataGrid Data=@Forecasts.Where(x=>x.TemperatureC==MasterRecord.TemperatureC) ShowFilterRow=false CssClass="MainGrid" @ref="MyGridDetail"
                        RowUpdatingAsync=@(OnRowUpdating)
                        RowInsertingAsync=@(OnRowInserting)>
                <DxDataGridCommandColumn>
                    <HeaderCellTemplate>
                            <a class="oi oi-plus" @onclick="@(() => MyGridDetail.StartRowEdit(null))" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
                        </HeaderCellTemplate>

                    <CellTemplate>
                        <a class="oi oi-pencil" @onclick="@(() => MyGridDetail.StartRowEdit(context))" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
                    </CellTemplate>
                </DxDataGridCommandColumn>
                <DxDataGridColumn Field=@nameof(WeatherForecast.TemperatureC) Caption="Temp. (C)"></DxDataGridColumn>
                <DxDataGridColumn Field=@nameof(WeatherForecast.TemperatureF) Caption="Temp. (F)"></DxDataGridColumn>
                <DxDataGridDateEditColumn Field=@nameof(WeatherForecast.Date) DisplayFormatString="dd/MM/yyyy"
                                          EditFormatString="dd/MM/yyyy"></DxDataGridDateEditColumn>
            </DxDataGrid>

            @code {
                [Parameter]
                public WeatherForecast[] Forecasts { get; set; }

                [Parameter]
                public WeatherForecast MasterRecord{ get; set; }

                [Parameter]
                public WeatherForecastService ForecastService { get; set; }



                DevExpress.Blazor.DxDataGrid<WeatherForecast> MyGridDetail = null;

                async Task OnRowUpdating(WeatherForecast dataItem, IDictionary<string, object> newValue)
                {
                    Forecasts = await ForecastService.Update(dataItem, newValue);
                }
                async Task OnRowInserting(IDictionary<string, object> newValue)
                {
                    //forecasts = await ForecastService.Insert(newValue);
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not recommend using one **ref** variable for several instances. It may cause such collisions. Isolate your detail grid in a separate component to resolve the issue.